# Avoid getting horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

I have a table with two rows and two column. This table itself is contained in a hierarcy of tables/tr/td. 
First row just has really long text
Second row has two columns. First column with radio buttons and second column with some other controls. Second row is looking good.
Problem is that because of the long text in first row, I am getting a horizontal scroll bar that I want to avoid. I would like long text to wrap to another line in first row. Any ideas how can that be done.

```
<table border="0" style="width: 100%; ">
    <tr  style="width: 100%;">
        <td  style="padding: 10px; word-wrap:break-word" colspan="2">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  >some realllllllly long text</asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>this row has two column and working fine</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: hidden` or `table-layout:fixed`

Comment: nops; I am not sure how to use it. Any examples?

Comment: Check the Demo in the answer. Try removing the `CSS` part and you will get a scroll bar again. But with the `CSS` the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `CSS` for your table

```
table
{
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22Ls7f1w/1/)**

**Update after comment**

Use it in line like this:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed; ">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22Ls7f1w/2/)**

Comment: is there some way to do it in-line? Also can something be done with either the specific tr or td?

Comment: This text is now overflow into the parent table/tr/td element and not wrapping to next line. Sorry I didn't had it in my original question that I just included

Comment: do you simply want to add something like `<br>` and split the long text to multiple lines in same `td`?

Comment: the text size varies; its not fixed so i would like to do it via an appropriate style